# Azure ConnectionString using totally wrong login credentials

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, connection-string, azure-sql-database

I have created an ASP.NET MVC website which accesses a database, both of which are hosted in azure. I have created a specific login and user to access the database and can see them in SSMS. I see the login screen for the website. The trouble is when I try to log in, the login fails telling me that the user cannot be found.

Here's where it starts getting strange. The login ID that cannot be found is not the login that I created or that which is in my web.config (or my app.config). Instead it is the master user that I have to access the db server and other areas of my azure resources.

Here is the section from the web.config on my PC that was used to publish to azure:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="CSSL" connectionString="Server=tcp:svrmysqlserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=MyDatabase;User ID=sqlUser@svrmysqlserver;Password=q2wW£E;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=300;" providerName ="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The Error message said

```
Login failed for user 'MasterUser'.
```

I added some debug code to get the connection strings that were available and being used on the server and tried again. I got the following:

```
Login failed for user 'MasterUser'. 
ConfigurationManager[data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true] 
ConfigurationManager[] 
ConfigurationManager[Data Source=tcp:svrmysqlserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=MasterUser@svrmysqlserver;Password=MasterPassword;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False] 
ConfigurationManager[Data Source=tcp:svrmysqlserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=MasterUser@svrmysqlserver;Password=MasterPassword;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False] 
Database[Data Source=tcp:svrmysqlserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=MasterUser@svrmysqlserver;Password=MasterPassword;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False]
```

I attach a code snippet in answer to the comment below - where did I get the output from? I added code in the handler to get the current values of the connection strings before returning. The function is on the data context and is the first attempt to read data from the database.

```
    public ReturnInfo GetSystemRecord(out AppSystemRecord rec)
    {
        ReturnInfo ret = null;
        rec = new AppSystemRecord();

        //check that we have a hope of seeing this record - no records should have an ID of zero

        try
        {
            var query = from x in SystemRecord select x;        // ther should only ever be one
            if (query.Count() == 0)
            {
                SetupAdminUser();
                SystemRecord.Add(rec);
                SaveChanges();
            }
            else
                rec = query.FirstOrDefault();

            ret = new ReturnInfo();                 // defaults to all okay

            if (rec.Status == SystemStatus.Created || rec.Status == SystemStatus.Updated)
                SetupDefaultsForLookupTables();
            rec.Status = SystemStatus.Normal;
            SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            while (e.InnerException != null)
                e = e.InnerException;
            ret = new ReturnInfo(ErrorType.UnableToReadDomainObject, e.Message + "\r\n");
            // THIS IS THE IMPORTANT BIT TO GET THE CONNECTION DATA
            foreach (ConnectionStringSettings v in ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
            {
                ret.ErrorMessage += "ConfigurationManager[" + v.ConnectionString + "] " + "\r\n";
            }
            ret.ErrorMessage += "Database[" + Database.Connection.ConnectionString + "] " + "\r\n";
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

I searched my solution for any uses of MasterUser in any file but found none, nor any references to the password, which was the correct MasterUser password.

I deleted both the website and database and started again to be sure there were no files lying around in the cloud but without any joy. Any ideas what is going on? Is there some sort of cache that I haven't invalidated? is there some rule whereby there must be a connection to the master?

Your help and ideas would be gratefully received.
Craig

Comment: Where exactly did you capture those logs from?

Comment: I added code to the handler

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autogenerated default connection string vs. manually added one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330877/autogenerated-default-connection-string-vs-manually-added-one)

Comment: Check to see if the solution on this other question helps you out, Craig. I'm aware it's not a perfect duplicate but the answer might work.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, @Dan. It was interesting, but not quite my issue. I have since got round it - though without really understanding why, by supplying the connection string directly as a parameter AND taking the connection string out of the web.config file.

Comment: When you say directly as a parameter, do you mean for the web app? (I may be able to explain, but I didn't believe that was at play in the behavior you described.)

Comment: Hi @Dan, I took the connection string out of the web.config file and provided it directly to the DataContext constructor as a parameter. Then it seemed to start using the right user id. It was very strange that it happened like this and this is a workaround rather than a fix to my problem. That's why although it's not a problem for me anymore I've left the question as unanswered.

Comment: Hm. That's pecuilar- it's like the constructor you were using wasn't recognizing your config file.

Comment: Exactly right. I just couldn't understand it. Very strange. Thanks for thinking about this though.

Comment: No problem. (Glad it does not seem to be an Azure problem.) Hope someone can explain the behavior of that code.