# Configuration Manager returns default connection string

Tags: visual-studio, configuration

I've added the line

```
static private readonly string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString;
```

to my Console App project, and it returns a connection string despite the fact that I haven't yet set one up, and there is no config file anywhere in the solution folder.

It appears to be an ASP.NET database connection string:

```
data source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true
```

Where is VS getting this string from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this has been answered in full here:
[Autogenerated Default Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330877/autogenerated-default-connection-string-vs-manually-added-one)

Essentially it's a default from Machine.Config.